# AngularJS caching objects to avoid re-loading in new browser tabs

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

My `AngularJS` app behaves similarly to Gmail, in that it loads up a bunch of data to the browser with a "loading" screen. There are 3 javascript objects being retrieved from my database here and they take a little a few seconds each to load.

Once loaded, they permeate through the app and are used in various views and controllers.

However, if a user opens up one of the app's links in a new tab, they obviously to be re-loaded. I can see why this happens, but I'd much rather save the 5-10 seconds of loading time for the user and have someway of sharing the data between different tabs.

Is this possible at all, perhaps using Angular's `$cookie` service or caching? I'm quite new to this style of programming so detailed answers are most definitely appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to cache for the duration of the app?

Comment: you could try localstorage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: Local storage in AngularJS: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the two people above answered, you can do this via LocalStorage. However, if you begin to write your data to the LocalStorage, and try to keep the LocalStorage in sync with your server storage, that task quickly becomes a full time job that is full of bugs. Use a library for this.

[THIS SITE](http://jster.net/blog/javascript-storage-libraries-explored#.UmUux5Rgaxw) has a few options.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the resources and advice - especially the word of warning about syncing local storage with server, as this is exactly what I was gonna do! Cheers.